# Trying to create a GtkTreeView from Python, doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, application-development, gtk, pygi

I'm writing an app using Gtk/PyGI, and I need to create a sidebar with a [Nautilus-like tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k18BH.png).

However, Gtk refuses to cooperate with me. I tried both with Glade and GtkBuilder (creating the GtkTreeStore with one `gchararray` column) and with this code:

```
def create_widgets(self):
  self.hbox = Gtk.Box(orientation = Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
  self.add(self.hbox)
  self.treestore = Gtk.TreeStore(str)
  self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView(self.treestore)
  self.treestore.append(["Item 1"])
  self.treestore.append(["Item 2"])
  self.hbox.pack_start(self.treeview, True, True, 0)
```

Both versions raise a `TypeError: Expected Gtk.TreeIter, but got StructMeta` starting at the first `self.treestore.append()` in my code and trickling down through the library's files.

I thought it's because GtkTreeStore's `.append` also takes a GtkTreeIter, but if I pass something like "0" as the first argument nothing changes, if I pass something like `self.treestore.get_iter("0")` it errors out saying it's an invalid tree path, and if I pass `None` it works, but shows [an empty window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZRUY.png).

I tried replacing the GtkTreeStore with a GtkListStore. The result doesn't error out - instead, it shows [the very same empty window as before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZRUY.png).

So, what am I doing wrong? I went through [the docs](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/treeview.html) time and time again, but I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Gtk.TreeStore` and `Gtk.ListStore` are different in that a `Gtk.ListStore` is a flat list where you append rows as a list, whereas a `Gtk.TreeStore` holds parent/child data, so it takes the parent as `Gtk.TreeIter` and a list as row.

```
parent_iter = treestore.append(None, ["parent row"])
treestore.append(parent_iter, ["child row"])
```

http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/treeview.html#Gtk.TreeStore.append

As for the empty window, have a look at the [views](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/treeview.html#the-view) section of the docs.

Comment: Thanks, the views section was what I needed. Could have sworn I tried adding a column before, but it didn't work. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this demo which uses a TreeStore: http://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject/tree/demos/gtk-demo/gtk-demo.py